# If row doesnt contain another row, merge them

Tags: mysql, merge, row, concatenation

I have  2 columns "name" - products and some name is without vendor, and "vendor" column, always with vendor name.

I want to check, if "name" doesn't conatin "vendor" value, concat it.

Firstly I tryed do select, but no hope to fix

Thank you!

```
SELECT * FROM `products` where name not  LIKE ('%', vendor, '%');
```

Comment: Do you mean `LIKE CONCAT('%', vendor, '%')`

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question you want to concat column `vendor` and `name` if there are no already vendor value into name value.

You can use this query (see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60f04/4)):

```
SELECT IF(LOCATE(`vendor`, `name`) > 0, `name`, CONCAT(`vendor`, ' ', `name`))
`name`, `vendor` FROM `products`;
```